# Webpack images from css file after build doesn't copy

Tags: webpack, css-loader, webpack-file-loader

When I run `npm run build` the images from `.html` files are loaded / copied. But the ones from the css file doesn't get copied in the final `dist/assets/img` folder.

And if I use `copy-webpack-plugin`, everything is ok `assets` folder is copied. But I `cache` the images so I will have duplicates with the ones in `.html` files.

Here you have my [config files](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/a67e461813c6782c8693c564e059a30f).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out. Got the solution from [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/44#issuecomment-379059788).

Here is [the previous gist](https://gist.github.com/grecdev/a67e461813c6782c8693c564e059a30f) that i modified, only for `config` and `prod` files.

Answer (score 0):

You have disabled url/image-set functions handling for css-loader in file `webpack.prod.js` line 52:

`{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { url: false, sourceMap: true } },`

replace it with:

`{ loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },`

Comment: Now it copies the image but in the end `css` file the source is not the same as in development from `scss` file. 

In `scss` file is: `background: url('../imgs/photo')`

And in `css` file is: `background: url('assets/imgs/photo')`.

Comment: @grecdev. That is good. Now problem is with [publicPath](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath). You need to add proper path: in `webpack.prod.js` between lines 16 and 17

Comment: @grecdev try add `publicPath: '/'`. Can't guarantee that will solve your problem but it might. If not read [the docs](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#outputpublicpath). Check your css output when you do production build and what it should be in order to upload your image and adjust your `publicPath` respectively

Comment: Now in `scss` development file have: `background: url("../imgs/photo.jpg") no-repeat center/cover;`

And in build file i have: `background:url(assets/imgs/photo.78c8366fa04b91d536cd4a3d5b3b9334.jpg)`

So i see that in build file the url is not relative to the image hmm..

Comment: @grecdev and what is expected path in build file? Please check your build folder. Be sure that if you replace wrong url with correct url using devtools you should see your image.

Comment: I wanted to say that the `url` from `build end files` should be the same as `scss dev files`. but in build is `assets/imgs` not `../imgs` as it should be.

Comment: It depends on how you serve your files on server side. If you serve all your files from `dist` folder your path most likely should be "/assets/imgs", notice "/" at the beginning. And not "../imgs". But I don't know how you serve them exactly. You may try `publicPath: '../'`